# Subclassing a class that implements singleton thought metaclass

Tags: python, inheritance, namespaces, metaclass

I have this code:

```
class Singleton(type):

  def __call__(cls,*args,**kwargs):
    if cls.created is None :
      print('called')
      cls.created = super().__call__(*args,**kwargs)
      return cls.created
    else:
      return cls.created
  def __new__(cls,name,base,attr,**kwargs):
    return super().__new__(cls,name,base,attr,**kwargs)


class OnlyOne(metaclass=Singleton):
  created = None
  def __init__(self,val):
      self.val = val

class OnlyOneTwo(OnlyOne):
  pass


k = OnlyOne(1)
a = OnlyOneTwo(2)



print(a.val)
print(k.val)
print('a.created: {0} - b.created: {1}'.format(id(a.created),id(k.created)))
```

I'm new to Python 3 so I decided to do some little experiment and playing around Python's metaclasses.

Here, I attempted to make a metaclass that will strict a class to a single instance when set.

I'm not sure yet if this works but whenever I try to do:

```
k = OnlyOne(1)
a = OnlyOneTwo(2)
```

the output will be:

```
called
1
1
```

which means that `OnlyOneTwo` wasn't set but when I try to do:

```
a = OnlyOneTwo(2)
k = OnlyOne(1)
```

the output will be:

```
called
called
2
1
```

Can someone help me traceback? I'm somehow confused but here are my initial questions/thoughts:

1. Does `OnlyOneTwo`'s `created` property the same as `OnlyOne`'s ? because I get different results through `id()` depending on which one I defined first. It's different if it's `OnlyOneTwo` first but it's the same if it's `OnlyOne` first.
2. How come `created` is still `None` if I will run `a = OnlyOneTwo(2)
   print(OnlyOne.created)` ?

Comment: Maybe start by adding ```print('__new__\tcls:{}\n\tname:{}\n\tbase:{}\n\tattr:{}'.format(cls,name,base,attr))``` as the first line of ```__new__```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give this a shot.  I think the symptom is due to the assignment, `cls.created = ...` in `__call__`.

When the class objects are first created `OnlyOneTwo.created` *points to* `OnlyOne.created`.  They both have the same `id`, which is the same as `None`.

```
>>> id(None)
506773144
>>> id(OnlyOne.created), id(OnlyOneTwo.created)
(506773144, 506773144)
```

If you make an instance of `OnlyOne` first, the instance is assigned to `OnlyOne.created` (it no longer *points to* `None`) but `OnlyOneTwo.created` still points to `OnlyOne.created` - they are still the same thing so that when `OnlyOneTwo` is called, the else clause of the conditional is executed.

```
>>> a = OnlyOne('a')
called
>>> id(OnlyOne.created), id(OnlyOneTwo.created)
(54522152, 54522152)
>>> z = OnlyOneTwo('z')
>>> id(OnlyOne.created), id(OnlyOneTwo.created)
(54522152, 54522152)
>>> id(a)
54522152
```

When you make an instance of `OnlyOneTwo` first, that instance is assigned to `OnlyOneTwo.created`, it no longer *points to* `OnlyOne.created`.  `OnlyOne.created` still *points to* `None`.

```
>>> id(None)
506773144
>>> id(OnlyOne.created), id(OnlyOneTwo.created)
(506773144, 506773144)
>>> z = OnlyOneTwo('z')
called
>>> id(OnlyOne.created), id(OnlyOneTwo.created)
(506773144, 54837544)
>>> id(z)
54837544
```

Now when you make an instance of `OnlyOne` the if condition is True and the instance is assigned to `OnlyOne.created`

```
>>> a = OnlyOne('a')
called
>>> id(OnlyOne.created), id(OnlyOneTwo.created)
(54352752, 54837544)
>>> id(a)
54352752
```

I often find myself re-reading [Binding of Names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#binding-of-names) and [Resolution of Names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) - also [A Word About Names and Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects) and [Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

---

I feel that I haven't actually explained the mechanism - I don't really understand how the *child* class attribute ***points to*** the base class attribute - it is something different than `a = b = None`.

Maybe:

- Initially the child class doesn't actually *have* the attribute, the *points to* mechanism is how inheritance is implemented, since  it doesn't *have* the attribute, the attribute is searched for in its parent(s).
- Even though the parent class attribute *changes* with instantiation, the child class still doesn't *have* the attribute and has to search for it and it finds the *new* thing.
- If the child class is instantiated first the assignment in the metaclass *gives* the attribute to the child class - now it *has* it and it doesn't have to search for it.

Re-reading the Custom Classes section of the [Standard Type Hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) in the docs triggered that brain dump.

I feel like I've been here before, maybe even in SO.  Hope I remember it this time and don't have to figure it out again.

---

If you want to fix your Singleton there are numerous options if you search for them.  Using a metaclass it seems the instance is held in the metaclass, not the the class itself. [Creating a singleton in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6760685/2823755), SO Q&A, is a good start.